Spring Boot multithread application
I'm trying to make a Spring Boot app that starts new thread which is doing the same job every second until thread pool is all used.  I looked on available scheduling libraries, but I don't see any that can start new thread while other one is working.
For example, when I use this
<task:executor id="myExecutor"  pool-size="5" />
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="5" />
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="someBean" method="doSomething" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>

Whatever I use, fixed-delay or fixed-rate or cron in task:scheduled tag, the effect is the same. A new thread is started only after the old one is finished. Do I just have to start threads manually, or is there some way to configure this in XML or by annotations?

Use fixed-rate instead of fixed-delay.

with fixed-rate it works exactly the same way. only one thread is working at the same time.

AFAIK, only if someBean is defined to not allow concurrent execution.

founded solution
in main spring boot class I added @EnableAsync
and above doSomething method I added @Async
now it works with fixed-rate as I wanted, thanks a lot for the help.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
